# Recyclerview filter picks previous element data after Filteres

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am filtering my recyclerview data with onQueryTextChange method, the filter is working fine, however when I am clicking on a element after filter, it still picks up the element that was placed before the filter. Could some one point me out what I am doing wrong here.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
 {

    List<DataAdapter> DataAdapterClassList;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

     EditText etSearch;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;

    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewadapter;

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;

    ArrayList<String> BankNames;

    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    String HTTP_SERVER_URL = "http://hiddenforsecurity.com?method=apiTest";

    View ChildView;

    int RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS;

    LinearLayout lyt, icicBtn, hdfcBtn, axisBtn, sbiBtn, pnbBtn, yesBtn;

     private static int firstVisibleInListview;




     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        DataAdapterClassList = new ArrayList<>();

        BankNames = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);

        lyt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout1);

        final Intent go = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StateList.class);


        icicBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.icicBtn);
        hdfcBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hdfcBtn);
        axisBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.axisBtn);
        sbiBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sbiBtn);
        pnbBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pnbBtn);
        yesBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yesBtn);

        final Intent i = new Intent(this, StateList.class);


        // JSON data web call function call from here.
        JSON_WEB_CALL();

        //RecyclerView Item click listener code starts from here.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    return true;
                }

            });

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                ChildView = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if (ChildView != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                    //Getting RecyclerView Clicked item value.
                    RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(ChildView);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, BankNames.get(RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Printing RecyclerView Clicked item clicked value using Toast Message.
                    //i.putExtra("selectedbank", BankNames.get(RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS));
                    //startActivity(i);

                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });

        icicBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "ICICI BANK LIMITED");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });

        axisBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "AXIS BANK");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });

        hdfcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "HDFC BANK");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });

        sbiBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "STATE BANK OF INDIA");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });
        pnbBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "PUNJAB NATIONAL BANK");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });
        yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "YES BANK");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });
    }


    public void JSON_WEB_CALL(){

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_SERVER_URL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);


                GetDataAdapter2.setBankName(json.getString("BANK"));

                //Adding subject name here to show on click event.
                BankNames.add(json.getString("BANK"));

            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DataAdapterClassList.add(GetDataAdapter2);

        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(DataAdapterClassList, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);

    }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

         MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
         SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

         searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

         return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


         final List<DataAdapter> filteredModelList = filter(DataAdapterClassList, newText);
         if (filteredModelList.size() > 0) {
             recyclerViewadapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
             return true;
         } else {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return false;
         }

     }

     private List<DataAdapter> filter(List<DataAdapter> models, String query) {
         query = query.toLowerCase();

         final List<DataAdapter> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
         for (DataAdapter model : models) {
             final String text = model.getBankName().toLowerCase();
             if (text.contains(query)) {
                 filteredModelList.add(model);
             }
         }

         recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(filteredModelList, MainActivity.this);
         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
         recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
         recyclerViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         return filteredModelList;
     }

 }
```

RecyclerviewAdapter.java

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    public DataAdapter dataAdapter;

    List<DataAdapter> dataAdapters;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

        super();

        this.dataAdapters = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        dataAdapter =  dataAdapters.get(position);

        viewHolder.TextViewName.setText(dataAdapter.getBankName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return dataAdapters.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView TextViewName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            TextViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewCard) ;

        }
    }

    public void setFilter(List<DataAdapter> bankNames) {
        dataAdapters = new ArrayList<>();
        dataAdapters.addAll(bankNames);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Please have a look at these screenshot for better understanding of my query.

When I click on a item before filter, Toast displays correct data.
[Unfiltered Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFxTT.jpg)

When I click on a item after filtering, Toast still displays the data from the above screenshot, where as it was supposed to show HDFC BANK.[Filtered Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMcGw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are changing dataset in list view but later on in Toast you reffer to `BankNames` which is different dataset.

In your example list has ony 1 element due to filters. While you click it, clicked index will be in fact 0, not x as you would require and later on you are picking 0 indexed bank from `BankNames` not from filtered result set.

To get things right, use the same dataset for list view and data fetch.
You can do that, by simply creating `filteredBankNames` collection that will contain currently filtered results, and pass that to your list view. In the same time, in on click event, pick bank name from `filteredBankNames` as well insteed of `BankNames`

So for example:

```
     // make this not final local variable, but a field in activity so you can remember filtered items
     final List<DataAdapter> filteredModelList = filter(DataAdapterClassList, newText);
     if (filteredModelList.size() > 0) {
         recyclerViewadapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
         return true;
     } else {
```

and with `Toast`

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, filteredModelList.get(RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, which Data set am I actually supposed to show after filter is performed, in the context to my my code above, if you could help me with the code a little, I will be grateful.

Comment: Its up to you, the thing is, that you are showing one dataset to the user, and you are picking items from very different one in onclick event. Use the same dataset (like filtered one) for showing and getting data (for Toast in this case) and you will be fine.

Comment: I am trying to implement this, after learning from a tutorial online, which took a lot of time to figure out. Kindly assist me on this, and if you could write a small snippet of code that could fix this and make sense, where the toast shows what it is supposed to after filtering

Comment: I just did as example in my answer